# python-language-server config file location

Tags: neovim, python-language-server

I'm trying to use `flake8` as the default python linter using `python-language-server` on neovim v0.5.

[python-lsp documentation](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server/blob/develop/CONFIGURATION.md) says to set `pylsp.configurationSources` to `['flake8']`, but doesn't specify which file to edit.

Where does the python-lsp-server config file reside?

Answer (score 0):

According to [flake8 documentation](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.8.4/user/configuration.html), the location of flake8 config varies based on systems, on Linux and Mac, it is `~/.config/flake8`, and for Windows, it is `$HOME\.flake8` (`$HOME` is like `C:\\Users\sigmavirus24`). The content should be in INI format:

```
[flake8]
max-line-length = 100
max-complexity = 30
ignore =
    # missing whitespace around arithmetic operator
    E226,
    # line break before/after binary operator
    W503,
    W504,
    # expected 1 blank line, found 0
    E301,E302,
```

To suppress a single warning, it is also handy to add `# noqa: F841`-like (change the code to the actual code you want to use) comment string to suppress it.

Ref: https://jdhao.github.io/2020/11/05/pyls_flake8_setup/#config-location